# Uncaught TypeError: _index2.default.extend is not a function when upgrade to vue 3.x

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Today I upgrade my google chrome extension from vue 1.x to 3.x, when I run the upgraded app, the console shows error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _index2.default.extend is not a function
    at Object../src/popup/st.js (commons1.js:12741)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:23)
    at Object../src/popup/app.js (commons1.js:12543)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:23)
    at Object../src/popup/index.js (commons1.js:12687)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:23)
    at popup.js:163
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (popup.js:57)
    at popup.js:164
    at popup.js:166
```

This is my `st.js` file:

```
import client from './client';
import Widget from '../public/widget/index';
import getOptions from '../public/default-options';
import {read} from '../public/clipboard';

export default Widget.extend( {
  client ,
  async compiled() {
    this.inline = true;
    this.showForm = true;
    const {defaultApi , autoClipboard} = await getOptions( [ 'defaultApi' , 'autoClipboard' ] );

    this.query.api = defaultApi;
    if ( autoClipboard ) {
      this.query.text = read();
      this.safeTranslate();
    }
  } ,
  ready() {
    setTimeout( ()=> this.$els.textarea.focus() , 200 );
  }
} );
```

I am seaching from internet seems no one facing the same problem. what should I do to upgrade my legacy code to avoid this error? this is the vue dependencies:

```
"vue": "^3.2.28",
"vue-router": "^3.2.28"
```

the `Widget` which imported from `../public/widget/index` look like this:

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent( {
  template ,
  data : ()=>({})
})
```

I am using google chrome extension there is no main.js, but this is my popup entry js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import template from './tpl.html';
import chromeCall from 'chrome-call';
import getOptions from '../public/default-options';
import {getTabLocation,isHostEnabled} from '../public/util';
import ST from './st';

export const appOptions = {
  el : 'app' ,
  template ,
  data : {
    _host : null ,
    canInject : false ,
    enabled : false
  } ,
  methods : {
    async switchEnable() {
      const {_host} = this.$data ,
        enabled = this.enabled = !this.enabled ,
        {excludeDomains} = await getOptions( 'excludeDomains' );

      if ( enabled ) {
        excludeDomains.splice( excludeDomains.indexOf( _host ) , 1 );
      } else {
        excludeDomains.push( _host );
      }
      return chromeCall( 'storage.local.set' , { excludeDomains } );
    }
  } ,
  components : {
    'st-box' : ST
  } ,
  async ready() {
    const locationObj = await getTabLocation();
    if ( locationObj ) {
      this.$data._host = locationObj.host;
      this.canInject = true;
      this.enabled = await isHostEnabled( locationObj );
    }
  }
};

/* istanbul ignore if */
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'testing' ) {
  window.onload = ()=> {
    setTimeout( ()=> new Vue( appOptions ) , 0 );
  };
}
```

**Tried 1:** I am replace `Widget.extend` with `defineComponent` seems did not work as expect. I read this [issue](https://github.com/smronju/vue-webcam/issues/6) but still did not figure out how to fix it.

**Tried 2:** tried also tweak my code like this follow this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/629) but seems did not work too:

```
import client from './client';
import Widget from '../public/widget/index';
import getOptions from '../public/default-options';
import {read} from '../public/clipboard';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent( { 
  extends:Widget({
  client ,
  async compiled() {
    this.inline = true;
    this.showForm = true;
    const {defaultApi , autoClipboard} = await getOptions( [ 'defaultApi' , 'autoClipboard' ] );

    this.query.api = defaultApi;
    if ( autoClipboard ) {
      this.query.text = read();
      this.safeTranslate();
    }
  } ,
  ready() {
    setTimeout( ()=> this.$els.textarea.focus() , 200 );
  }
} )});
```

Comment: can you post your `main.js`?

Comment: I have pasted my popup entry `app.js` @saibbyweb